# change permission of a Office 365 one drive document from "Edit" to "View" & vice versa using REST API?

Tags: api, rest, office365, onedrive

I Can create document in One drive using Office 365 REST API but is there any way to change permission of created document from "Edit" to "View" & vice versa using REST API?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it doesn't look like you'll be able to update the file permissions.  The documentation on "https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/files-rest-operations#FileoperationsUpdatefileproperties" shows that you can update the name or move an item according to the request body parameters.